# select dept names who have more than 2 employees whose salary is greater than 1000

Tags: sql

How would do the following in SQL

"select dept names who have more than 2 employees whose salary is greater than 1000" ?

```
DeptId DeptName
------ --------
1          one
2          two
3        three

EmpId DeptId Salary
----- ------ ------
121      1    2000
122      1    2000
123      1    5000
124      1    4000
131      2    2000
132      2    6000
133      2    1000
134      2    1000
125      3    1000
126      3   20000


RESULT: one
```

Comment: 1st table name = DEPARTMENT; 2nd table name = EMPLOYEE;

Comment: Why does employee #121 have three salaries - one in dept 1 and 2 in dept 3?

Comment: Larry I have removed the discrepancy from the Question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT D.DeptName FROM
Department D WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                    FROM Employee E 
                    WHERE E.DeptID = D.DeptID AND
                            E.Salary > 1000) > 2
```

Comment: This worked as expected and to me it seems to be the best answer. Please let me know if anyone differs.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT DEPTNAME
FROM(SELECT D.DEPTNAME,COUNT(EMPID) AS TOTEMP
     FROM DEPT AS D,EMPLOYEE AS E
     WHERE D.DEPTID=E.DEPTID AND SALARY>1000
     GROUP BY D.DEPTID
     )
WHERE TOTEMP>2;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select min(DEPARTMENT.DeptName) as deptname 
from DEPARTMENT
inner join employee on
DEPARTMENT.DeptId = employee.DeptId
where Salary > 1000
group by (EmpId) having count(EmpId) > =2
```

Comment: Pankaj this didn't work. I would be thankful if you post the corrected solution. I would learn.

Answer (score 2):

hope this helps

```
select DeptName from DEPARTMENT inner join EMPLOYEE using (DeptId) where Salary>1000 group by DeptName having count(*)>2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select D.DeptName from [Department] D where D.DeptID in 
( 
    select E.DeptId from [Employee] E
    where E.Salary > 1000
    group by E.DeptId
    having count(*) > 2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select deptname from dept_1
where exists
(
SELECT DeptId,COUNT(*)        
FROM emp_1  
where salary>1000
and emp_1.deptid=dept_1.deptid   
GROUP BY DeptId 
having count(*)>2)
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, here, it is a good practice to explain why to use your solution and not just how. That will make your answer more valuable and help further reader to have a better understanding of how you do it. I also suggest that you have a look on our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score 1):

1:list name of all employee who earn more than RS.100000 in a year.

2:give the name of employee who earn heads the department where employee with employee I.D

Answer (score 0):

My main advice would be to steer clear of the `HAVING` clause (see below):

```
WITH HighEarners AS
     ( SELECT EmpId, DeptId
         FROM EMPLOYEE
        WHERE Salary > 1000 ), 
     DeptmentHighEarnerTallies AS 
     ( SELECT DeptId, COUNT(*) AS HighEarnerTally
         FROM HighEarners
        GROUP 
           BY DeptId )
SELECT DeptName
  FROM DEPARTMENT NATURAL JOIN DeptmentHighEarnerTallies
 WHERE HighEarnerTally > 2;
```

---

The very early SQL implementations lacked derived tables and `HAVING` was a workaround for one of its most obvious drawbacks (how to select on the result of a set function from the `SELECT` clause). Once derived tables had become a thing, the need for `HAVING` went away. Sadly, `HAVING` itself didn't go away (and never will) because nothing is ever removed from standard SQL. There is no need to learn `HAVING` and I encourage fledgling coders to avoid using this historical hangover.

Comment: On what do you base your advice to steer clear of "HAVING" - an operator that seems designed specifically to answer the OP's question in a clear and easy fashion?

Comment: That article contains a very idiosyncratic view of HAVING.  The argument against it is pretty lame (that people have to learn the difference between operating on the candidate rows and the aggregated result set).  Can you possibly argue that the solution you gave is superior Pankaj's?

Comment: @onedaywhrn - your solution worked but I am naive to understand how to replace the values and get it from the Tables.

Comment: Overkill. Why to use? "Because you can"?